# what is the range or ms sql xml argument?

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using mssql with j2ee spring framework. 
When insert a data to a table, i am using bulk insert with xml argument in mssql.
Can you anyone say how much data we can pass using this.
I would like to know this range with xml argument.

T.Saravanan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[On the SQL Server side, it is is 2GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx)

> The stored representation of xml data type instances cannot exceed 2 gigabytes (GB) in size

"Stored" means after [some processing for efficiency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190965.aspx)

> SQL Server internally represents XML in an efficient binary representation that uses UTF-16 encoding. User-provided encoding is not preserved, but is considered during the parse process.