# greek language in xml column sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, encoding

I have exported my data to text File. It was open in file as utf-8 encoding. Then I've changed some text and tried to import it back to the database but now there are no Greek letters.

Coding is gone :(

How should I encode text file with inserts so that I don't loose coding after insert to database ?

thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show us the SQL code and tables please?

Comment: Might not be an issue but keep in mind that SQL Server will always store XML using utf-8 encoding. So if your application is not saving the file as utf-8 after edits you make it can result in characters being interpreted incorrectly as SQL Server attempts to convert it back into utf-8.

Comment: file is converted to utf-8, still doesnt work

Comment: @Yuck: The UTF is decided by the string and the encoding in the data. Internally it is always UTF-16  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857760/saving-xml-contents-with-iso-8859-1-encoding-using-entity-framework-into-sql-serv/6857882#6857882 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888984/what-is-the-range-or-ms-sql-xml-argument/6889266#6889266

Comment: How can I convert my utf-8 file to utf-16 so that I can easily insert it to database ? I ve got more thank 2 k insert commands and as I cand understand I just need to convert that file to utf-16

Comment: @gruber: you don't have to convert it. What you have done is INSERTed it as a varchar literal most likely before it became xml. However, you haven't given us any sample code to verify this. And read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857760/saving-xml-contents-with-iso-8859-1-encoding-using-entity-framework-into-sql-serv/6857882#6857882

Answer (score 0):

> tried to import it back to the database but now there are no Greek letters

Based on the insert from your other post:  [problem with greek encoding while inserting sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373716/problem-with-greek-encoding-while-inserting-sql-server) where you discuss a similar problem, I see two likely culprits:

1. the destination column [MC_LIST].[data] is a non Unicode datatype (such as nvarchar, nchar). the varchar datatype will store the Greek characters as ?
2. and/or you are inserting string literals without the N prefix
   Example, this will fail:

> INSERT INTO myDB.[MC_LIST]
> ([data])   VALUES
> ('1gr/products/how-does-nioxin-works-page.aspxaltΠΡΟΣΕΓΓΙΣΗ
> ΦΡΟΝΤΙΔΑΣ ΤΗΣ
> ΕΠΙΔΕΡΜΙΔΑΣ/m/photo/box-4.jpgΚάθε
> προϊόν lala περιέχει έναν εξειδικευμένο συνδυασμό συστατικών
> επιστημονικής προέλευσης. ΟΙ ΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΕΣ
> ΜΑΣΠΡΟΣΕΓΓΙΣΗ ΦΡΟΝΤΙΔΑΣ ΤΗΣ
> ΕΠΙΔΕΡΜΙΔΑΣ') ;

Whereas this will work:

```
INSERT INTO myDB.[MC_LIST] 
    ([data]) 
 VALUES 
    (N'<data><id>1</id><language>gr</language><szonelinkdest>/products/how-does-nioxin-works-page.aspx</szonelinkdest><szoneimgalt>alt</szoneimgalt><title>ΠΡΟΣΕΓΓΙΣΗ ΦΡΟΝΤΙΔΑΣ ΤΗΣ ΕΠΙΔΕΡΜΙΔΑΣ</title><szoneimg>/m/photo/box-4.jpg</szoneimg><szonedesc>Κάθε προϊόν lala περιέχει έναν εξειδικευμένο συνδυασμό συστατικών επιστημονικής προέλευσης. </szonedesc><szonelinkname>ΟΙ ΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΕΣ ΜΑΣ</szonelinkname><szonetitle>ΠΡΟΣΕΓΓΙΣΗ ΦΡΟΝΤΙΔΑΣ ΤΗΣ ΕΠΙΔΕΡΜΙΔΑΣ</szonetitle></data>') ;
```